# Change alternate row colors in datatables

Tags: datatables

I am trying to change the color of rows in datatable using the below CSS.

```
table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #E2E4FF; }
table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }
```

This change doesnt seem to affect first column in datatables, I can see the new color in other columns.

Can someone please let me know the reason for this issue?

Comment: Whether the first column is sorted? In datatable example it's sorted and it has another color too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the below css.

```
    table.dataTable td.sorting_1{ background-color: white; border:1px lightgrey; }
    table.dataTable td{ background-color: white;  border:1px lightgrey;}
    table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: white;  border:1px lightgrey;}
    table.dataTable tr.even{ background-color: white; border:1px lightgrey; }
```

Comment: The mouse selection highlight does not work with this approach. Is there no way to change the strip colour from datatable code internally inside options or something rather than modifying css?

Comment: this broke some of my other css settings.